# How to run some shell command in few databases in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Suppose i have 1000's databases in mongo with names -

project1Db, rtDB1, config_1DB, config_2DB, config_3DB, project2Db, rtDB2 ...

All databases have some collections (i.e. x, y, z...)

Now i want to rename collection name of databases which name starts with **config_{{somename}}**

i.e. config_1DB, config_2DB, config_3DB databases have collection name **student** i want to rename that to **person**.

Brute force approach will be go to databases one by one and run command.

`db.student.renameCollection("person")`

Is there anyway to rename in all databases at once?

Comment: What do you mean by "rename in all databases at once"? Apart from `db.getSiblingDB("config_2DB").getCollection("student").renameCollection("person")` there is no possibility. This command you can execute in a loop, all names can be variables.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I am looking for something like regex or shell script. Which can get all database which name starts with "config_" and rename collection name in those. Like there can be thousands databases with name starting with "config_".

Answer (score 1):

Could be like this:

```
db.adminCommand({ listDatabases: 1 }).databases.filter(x => x.name.startsWith("config_")).forEach(database => {
   db.getSiblingDB(database.name).getCollectionNames().filter(x => x == "student ").forEach(col => {
      db.getSiblingDB(database.name).getCollection(col).renameCollection("person");
   })
})
```